# laravel blade files, Your local changes would be overwritten by merge

Tags: git, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, git-pull

Almost every time I'm doing git pull on my production server I have this message:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        app/Http/helpers.php
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

Now it is helpers.php and next time it will be the next changed file.
It is not happening with all files but almost every time I run the git pull it happens.

I didn't make any change on the server it self. I'm logging in to production and immediately run to git pull commend.

My solution for it is:

```
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/master
```

but THE PROBLEM is that in the next pull request it happens again!

Any help to avoid this issue for my next pull requests...
Thank you in advanced

Comment: On the next pull request *executed immediately* after the `git reset --hard` without doing anything else in between? Hard to believe.

Comment: Could it be that `helpers.php` is generated or patched by some build step, and so doesn't belong under version control?

Comment: When you face this message what git diff shows?

Comment: @Kaz If I'm running immediately the git pull is telling me "already up to date". If I'm making push request from my localhost and then pull request on my server I receive the message about the specific file.

Comment: @Kaz It is not just helpers.php. I just made changes in one of my views and this is the message I get: error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        resources/views/admin/users/form.blade.php
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.

Comment: @Kaz as I see right now it happend only when I have changes in blade views... any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a file (`helpers.php`) that is being generated inside the git directory but not being added to git (so it's not tracked).

If you want reset to include it.  You can just add the file:

```
git add app/Http/helpers.php
```

then either reset or stash:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
git pull

git stash
git pull
git stash pop
```

Comment: It is not just helpers.php. I just made changes in one of my views and this is the message I get: error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        resources/views/admin/users/form.blade.php
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.